# ¿¿Por qué me da este error, enviando parametros de un JSP al Servlet, en JAVA?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

estoy tratando de enviar el "id" como parametro al doGet de un Servlet, pero me da el siguiente, error al clickear al boton Borrar:

```
<div class="container">
        <h1>Mis productos</h1>        
        <table >
            <thead>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Categoria</th>
            <th>Estado</th>
            <th>Precio</th>
            <th>Stock</th>
            <th>Acciones</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <%while (itProduct.hasNext()) {
                        Product p = itProduct.next();%>
                <tr>
                    <td data-label="Nombre"><%= p.getName()%></td>
                    <td data-label="Categoria"><%= p.getCategory().getName()%></td>
                    <td data-label="Estado"><%= p.getStatus()%></td>
                    <td data-label="Precio"><%= p.getPrecio()%></td>
                    <td data-label="Stock"><%= p.getStock()%></td>
                    <td data-label="Acciones">
                        <form action="/maven-api-client/ProductServlet" method ="get">
                            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="delete"/>
                            <input type="hidden" name="id" value=<%=p.getId() %>/>
                            <input type="submit" value="Borrar"/>
                        </form>

                        
                        <a href="EditarLibroController?isbn =">Editar</a></td>
                </tr>
                <%}%>                
            </tbody>           
        </table>
    </div>
```

Aquí esta el html, le paso el id y debe ir al doGet, pero por alguna razon toma el id como "2/" en vez de "2" ( tengo un registro en la lista con id=2) No entra en el doGet,.

```
 @Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

   
    String id = request.getParameter("id");

    if ("".equals(id) || id == null) {
        //Mostrar todos los productos
        ArrayList<Product> products = pm.getProducts();
        request.setAttribute("products", products);
        request.setAttribute("action", "showAll");
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("jsp/products.jsp");
        if (rd != null) {
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }
    } else{
        //Para editar la informacion de un producto.
        Product p = pm.getProductById(Integer.valueOf(id));
        request.setAttribute("product", p);
        request.setAttribute("action", "showById");
}
```

Me da la siguiente excepcion..

Estado HTTP 500 – Internal Server Error
Tipo Informe de Excepción

mensaje For input string: "2/"

Descripción El servidor encontró un error interno que hizo que no pudiera rellenar este requerimiento.

excepción

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2/"

Alguna forma de solucionar esto o otra forma de enviarle el "id" al servlet?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto, siempre.

Comment: De paso, ya que vas a añadir el código como texto, añade a la pregunta el código del servlet, por favor. No sabemos qué estás intentando hacer al recibir la info

Comment: Tienes unas comillas dobles faltantes en el formulario, en el campo del ID, entonces te incluye el slash de cierre de la etiqueta: `name="id" value=<%=p.getId() %>/>`. Es, pues, un error tipográfico :P

Comment: @Alfabravo graciaaaas, pensaba que al poner las " ", me tomaria como string "p.getId()", muchas gracias en serio

Comment: Noup, esas comillas son para el HTML, para que el navegador interprete bien la cosa. Las comillas se comportan como lo mencionas en el código Java :)